# How do I change the created date when I create a node?

Tags: 7

When i do POST request for create node i get error:

```
{
  "type": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1",
  "title": "Property created cannot be set.",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "Bad Request",
  "instance": ""
}
```

My restful resource provide this field:

```
protected function publicFields() {
  $public_fields = parent::publicFields();

  // Another fields ...

  $public_fields['created'] = [
    'property' => 'created',
  ];
}
```

I use [restful](https://www.drupal.org/project/restful) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem via hook_node_presave();

```
function hook_node_presave($node) {
  $node->created = "you_timestamp";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to other options, the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module could help you with this.

Start by downloading and installing the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module (and also enabling the Rules UI module that comes with it as well).

Following that, you can create a New Rule by going to Admin > Config > Workflow > Rules.

Click on the "Add new rules" button.

You can call the Rule whatever you'd like. What matters most is setting "React on event" to be "After saving new content" and then "Restrict by type" to the Content Type of your choice if this limited to one Content Type only.

[image]

When you go to the newly created rule, click on the "Add Action" link and then select "Set a data value"

[image]

In the Data field, type "node:created" and then click Continue.

[image]

Finally, you can specify what you want the new Created Date to be.

Comment: Andrew Webs, thank for you solution!

I solved this problem via hook_node_presave();

Comment: Oh, very nice! You essentially are doing the same thing but in the code rather than Rules UI. Good solution!